# Selecting rows where a value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

I have a table that shows a products price on a daily basis. A product has 3 prices: wholesale, volume and clearance.

The table is updated everyday with the current prices, most days no changes occur. However, I want to select the rows where one of the values has changed and I'm struggling for ideas. I've tried a group by but because prices go up and down this won't work.

```
select date_entered, 
       WholeSale,
       Volume,
       Clearance 
FROM pricetable 
where product = 'TANGO'
order by date_entered desc
```

The above selects all the rows from the table for a set product.

How can I make it so only rows where a change to, wholesale or volume or clearance has occurred.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `SQL` is a language, you need to tag your question with DBMS your using.eg: SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite ...

Comment: Apologies, I've added the tag now.

Comment: You can use `LAG()` to get the prev data and then compare it with the current data. _PrevData <> CurrentData_

Comment: *How can I make it so only rows where a change to, wholesale or volume or clearance has occurred* a change since when? The previous day?

Comment: Yes, anytime a price has been changed. So comparing it to the previous day would show that.

Comment: which SQL server version is it, since you are getting the LAG not recognised problem?

Comment: 10.50.4000.0 is the SQL Server version

Comment: The SQL version, which I think is SQL 2008, may not have LAG() implemented

Comment: It's `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2`

Comment: Let's go back to "previous day". On Monday (today), previous day is Sunday. You do not need to adjust for weekends, holidays, non-work days, etc.? Will **every product** have a row for any given date or might there be "holes" (i.e, missing rows)? Pricing can quickly become (and usually is) complicated.

Comment: @SMor There may be some holes when the procedure to update the table has failed to run.  Adjusting for weekends etc doesn't really matter. I just need the rows when a price has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p1.date_entered, 
       p1.WholeSale,
       p1.Volume,
       p1.Clearance 
FROM pricetable p1
CROSS APPLY
--cross apply to most recent prior record
(SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM pricetable p2 
            where p1.product = p2.product 
                and p2.date_entered < p1.date_entered 
                    order by p2.date_entered desc) CA
where p1.product = 'TANGO'
  and (p1.wholesale != CA.wholesale or p1.volume != CA.volume or p1.clearence != CA.clearence)
order by p1.date_entered desc
```

Comment: Hi @Cato this works thankyou! It takes a while to run, are there any noticeable parts where the speed could be increased?

Comment: does pricetable have an index?  If you add an index where the order is product then date entered, un-clustered, probably a unique index

Comment: Hi, sorry I understand what you meant now. Spoke to a colleague and they explained it. It's now running almost instantly with that in place. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

THE QUESTION WAS ORIGINALLY TAGGED SQL-SERVER (with no version).  This works for SQL Server 2012+:

Use `lag()`.  Something like this:

```
select pt.*
from (select pt.*,
             lag(wholesale) over (partition by product 
                                  order by date_entered) as prev_wholesale,
             lag(volume)    over (partition by product 
                                  order by date_entered) as prev_volume,
             lag(clearance) over (partition by clearance 
                                  order by date_entered) as prev_clearance
      from pricetable
      where product = 'TANGO'
     ) pt
where (prev_wholesale is null or prev_wholesale <> wholesale) or
      (prev_volume is null or prev_volume <> volume) or
      (prev_clearance is null or prev_clearance <> clearance)          
order by date_entered desc;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying LAG() isn't a recognized built in function. When I hover over it, it appears that is is as it know it returns an int. However, when trying to execute I get the error.

Comment: I don't think lag was supported in version 2008.  There work arounds.  Just search on 2008 lag.

Comment: My apologies for not tagging the version, and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Compare every row's values to the previous day's values:

```
SELECT * FROM pricetable p WHERE (p.product = 'TANGO') AND
(
    (p.WholeSale <> (SELECT WholeSale FROM pricetable WHERE product = 'TANGO' AND date_entered = dateadd(day, -1, p.date_entered))
OR
    (p.Volume <> (SELECT Volume FROM pricetable WHERE product = 'TANGO' AND date_entered = dateadd(day, -1, p.date_entered))
OR
    (p.Clearance <> (SELECT Clearance FROM pricetable WHERE product = 'TANGO' AND date_entered = dateadd(day, -1, p.date_entered))
)
```

Comment: Hi @forpas, this works it's just extremely slow. I'll try speed it up